# (Java) String declared in an 'if-else' statement cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, string, variables, if-statement

I know that variables are 'contained' within `if-else` statements if they are declared there, and can't be used outside the statement. But how do I declare one outside, then change its String within the `if-else`?

```
System.out.println("Is it day or night?");
String dayornight = scan.nextLine();

if(dayornight.equals("day")) {
    String brightness = "bright";   

} else if(dayornight.equals("night")) {
    String brightness = "dark";

}
System.out.println("Then it must be " + brightness + " outside." );
```

}

Comment: By doing just that. Declare it outside, and modify its value inside. The answer is in the question.

Comment: The *scope* of a variable is the area between the `{ }` characters most closely enclosing its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it outside:

```
String brightness;
if(dayornight.equals("day")) {
    brightness = "bright";   
} else if(dayornight.equals("night")) {
    brightness = "dark";
}
```

Not initializing it is good practice because then if there is a code path that can be executed without initializing it the code will not compile (like the code above). Changing `else if` to `else` in the code above or adding an `else` that will handle `dayornight` which isn't "day" or "night" will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A *local variable* (one that is declared inside a method) exists only within the innermost enclosing *block* (the curly braces). So you have created two *different* `brightness` variables, and each one only exists within one of the if/else branches. You need to declare the variable before the if/else:

```
String brightness = "";
if (dayornight.equals("day")) {
    brightness = "bright";   
} else if(dayornight.equals("night")) {
    brightness = "dark";
}
```

Also note that because you don't have an `else`, you need to initialize the variable when you declare it. Otherwise, the variable wouldn't have any value if the user enters something else than `"day"` or `"night"`, and the compiler won't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
System.out.println("Is it day or night?");
String dayornight = scan.nextLine();
String brightness = "";
if(dayornight.equals("day")) {
    brightness = "bright";   

} else if(dayornight.equals("night")) {
    brightness = "dark";

}
System.out.println("Then it must be " + brightness + " outside." );
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable declared inside the if block is out of scope outside. So you need to declare those variables above the block.